# Randomly written numbers in a game using java.util.Random

Tags: java

Here is my code.

I would like the window to look like this but I don't like the numbers to be written 1-36 like in this code. When I delete that code and try with:

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
```

and I define `z=20;` that field that was in the first place with 1-36 number, is deleted. 
My expected output is, to be a field like in the code below but the numbers to be different every time I open the game.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(600, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));

frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel center = new JPanel();
center.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 1, 1));
int z = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

        JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(++z));
        center.add(button);
    }
}
frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - I don't see any `Random` in your code, and it's not clear how your proposed change would fit in there, and what you expect to happen

Comment: Can the numbers be duplicated? Like 6-8-12-6-12 ... Or do they just have in a random order? Which would actually means a permutation of the numbers between 1 and 36

Comment: Random is old and not very random. I would suggest to use `SecureRandom` instead. SecureRandom's interface is also more convenient.

Comment: I was thinking the numbers to be duplicated like I give a limitation that i want them to be from 1-6 and only those numbers show in the 36 cubes.

Comment: Are you saying you want randoms without duplicates? Kind of hard to understand what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a method that will add random numbers in the indicated range as the names to your buttons. Somthng like this:

```
public class Frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {            
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9, 1, 1));

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(random(1, 6)));
            center.add(button);
        }
    }
    frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static int random(int min, int max) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        }
}
```